# In SqlAlchemy how can I configure ALL relationship()s to use a loading strategy by default?

Tags: sqlalchemy

The default SqlAlchemy relationship loading strategy is lazy.  If I want to change that to some other default, how would I do that?

I thought I saw it in the docs somewhere but I am not able to find it again.  Maybe I didn't see such a thing?

I suppose one way would be to write my own relationship() method that calls SqlAlchemy's relationship method but sets lazy to some other default if it's None, but is there a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to globally change the default argument to [`relationship.lazy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy).

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

relationship = partial(relationship, lazy='joined')
```

You can later override the lazy parameter like so:

```
class User:
    ...
    things = relationship('Thing', lazy='select')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner than what I was planning to do to wrap relationship.